# Gatsby: Regular Anchor Tags Not Working on Codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I must be missing something really simple, but can someone help me understand why the two in-route anchors do not have any effect in the Gatsby sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/k59wzx899r

PS: Regular anchor tags should be used for in-route links in Gatsby (ref. docs). Also, it works on local build.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I tested it in both development and production and it seems to work after changing the div's id to "foo" rather than "#foo". It still didn't work in CodeSandbox after making that change though, so I'm thinking that it might be something to do with their app. The production one I did is here: https://anchortest.netlify.com

I would have done this in the comments, but my rep is below 50.

Comment: Looks like an open issue:  https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1463